# How to insert and update data in just one button?

Tags: php, html, mysql

On the first click  of the button it adds data to database then on second click the button will update the data.Did someone know how to do it.. I have a code for insert but it can't update..

```
here is my html code
<html>
<head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="example.php">
<label>Content:</label>
<br>
<textarea name="cafnrcontent" id="cafnrcontent" rows="6" cols="43"></textarea>
</div>
<br>
<label>Posting:</label>
<br>
<label>From date:</label>
<input type="date" name="cafnrstart_date">
<label>To date:</label>
<input type="date" name="cafnrend_date">
<br><br>
  <input type="file" name="cafnrimage">
<br><br>
<label>Submitted by:</label>
<input type="text" id="cafnrauthor" name="cafnrauthor" value="">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" id="send" name="send" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</head>
</html>

<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';

  if(isset($_POST['send']))
{

$cafnrcontent =
mysqli_real_escape_string($DBcon,strip_tags($_POST['cafnrcontent'])); 
$cafnrimage = mysqli_real_escape_string($DBcon,strip_tags($_POST['cafnrimage']));
  $cafnrstart_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($DBcon,strip_tags($_POST['cafnrstart_date']));
  $cafnrend_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($DBcon,strip_tags($_POST['cafnrend_date']));
  $cafnrauthor = mysqli_real_escape_string($DBcon,strip_tags($_POST['cafnrauthor']));

     $Query = "INSERT INTO example (cafnrcontent,cafnrimage,cafnrstart_date,cafnrend_date,cafnrauthor) VALUES('$cafnrcontent','$cafnrimage','$cafnrstart_date','$cafnrend_date','$cafnrauthor')";

    $run = mysqli_query($DBcon, $Query);
             if (!$run) {
                echo 'Query Failed ';
            }
          }
```

Can anyone show me an example? Please help me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: On first click fetch last inserted record id. On second click if last inserted record id exists, then use this to update record.

Comment: may you send me here an example?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: We are not here to write code for you whenever you feel like it.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: yes. sorry I am late to show  you my codes ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
<a href="manage_user.php?action=add_new">Add New</a>
<a href="manage_user.php?action=edit&user_id=<?php echo $row['usrm_id']; ?>" >Edit</a>

<?php if(isset($_GET['action']) && ($_GET['action'] == "add_new")) 
{?>
    <input type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary" style="width:49%" value = "Save" name = "submit">
<?php
}
else
{?>
    <input type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary" style="width:49%" value = "Update" name = "submit">
<?php 
} ?>
```

if you want example using this code you will be able to display different button in same form. First try to Create the form  then if any error occurs then we are here to solve your problem. If you will not try you will not learn.

your insert query should be loke this:

```
INSERT INTO example (`cafnrcontent`,`cafnrimage`,`cafnrstart_date`,`cafnrend_date`,`cafnrauthor`) VALUES('".$cafnrcontent."','".$cafnrimage."','".$cafnrstart_date."','".$cafnrend_date."','".$cafnrauthor."')
```

Comment: Thanks. Kindly look at my codes. what do you think I need to add in my codes to make it update button on second click? thanks :)